# Normal on the point of curve

Tags: tangent-line

[image]

I tried to determine slope of curve at any variable point write the equation of normal but i am stucked what should i do?

Answer is 4

Comment: Can you show us some effort? What have you tried?

Comment: Look at the question paper and this is Jee types question here steps are short but thinking capacity required is large I can't wonder what to do next

Answer (score 0):

$3y=6x-5x^3$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2-5x^2$

If two lines are perpendicular and they have slopes $m_1,m_2$ then $m_1=\frac{-1}{m_2}$

Slope of normal $m= \dfrac{-1}{2-5x^2}$

Question says this line passes through origin . Equation will be y=mx

$y=\dfrac{-x}{2-5x^2}$

$x+2y=5x^2y$

Now put option values of x,y in this equation,if LHS=RHS then it is your correct option.

Comment: Ask me in comment if you didn't understand anything.